# Show input value

Tags: javascript, php

My problem:

```
<div id=mahashh></div>
<script> 
    var $mahash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
    document.getElementById("mahashh").innerHTML =  "Your ID " + $mahash; 
</script> 
<input type="text" id="mahashh" name="mahashh" value ="<?php echo $mahash ?>" >
```

Value Your ID shows correctly but input value is not shown.
Somebody help me show it in Input value. Thanks so much !

I'm newbie, not pro ^^!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question isn't very clear. Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. PHP is a **server-side** language. Javascript (not Java) is a **client-side** language. You're trying to output a Javascript variable into PHP which is not possible (at least, not in the way you're trying to do it)
2. A hash value from a URL is not processed by the server, and is therefore not available by default in PHP. Trying to send a hash fragment to the server from Javascript would involve something like AJAX, which is not likely what you want.

Without fully knowing your exact use-case here, you might be better off using [Query Parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) to pass simple information to the server.

As an example:

```
// http://yourlocalsite.com?id=yourId
<div id="mahashh"><?php echo 'Your ID ' . $_GET['id'] ?></div>
<input type="text" id="mahashh" name="mahashh" value ="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" >
```

That's a pretty simple (and rather insecure) example, but should give you a better start on what you're attempting to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm beginer ^^

Comment: I want get hash code from URL. And echo it in to input value

Comment: Okei. Get 'id' so easy and good for my idiea. Don't use hash (y) 
But I don't know why: rather insecure ?!

Comment: @MRSON This example is fine for what you want to do, but it's insecure in the sense that we're not sanitizing any input coming in from the `$_GET` request. In this particular example, we don't necessarily need to sanitize anything. But if you're supplying user-defined input for anything in the wild - either via GET, POST, or otherwise - then the data should be cleaned appropriately to prevent any kind of SQL/XSS attacks. But that's a completely separate discussion.

Comment: Hi i’m understande. Thanks so much. But my code is example for how it work. ‘Id’ get insert for ‘#submit’. And javascrip or JQuery action to do next maybe security ... i think so. i’m beginner

Answer (score 0):

In

```php
<?php echo $mahash ?>
```

you are trying to display value previously set in

```js
var $mahash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
```

and the reason of why it cant work is: php is a server-side language and javascript is a client-side lannguage. It means that php code is executed on different machine (imagine aws server) but javascript code is executed in your browser (your pc, not aws server). So, php and js can't communinate directly between each other.

Comment: Thanks you !

How i can get hash code from URL, then echo it to input value. I try do this with javascript and php but it not work ^^